# Dynamically importing a module in a subpackage

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to import a uberModule and retrieve the class "test" but getattr can't find it, why ? Thanks.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'test'
```

Here's my code, main.py:

```
from importlib import import_module
module = import_module("modules.uberModule")
cls = getattr(module, 'test')
```

uberModule.py :

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
       print "such wow"
```

Directory structure :

```
.
├── modules
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── uberModule
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── uberModule.py
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be:

```
module = import_module("modules.uberModule.uberModule")
```

unless `uberModule/__init__.py` imports the contents of `uberModule` (I guess not)

Comment: You have to write `modules` too, isn't it? If you think about it, it's logical :) If you don't want to write it twice, you could do something like `from .uberModule import *` inside the `uberModule/__init__.py`